# How to include credentials when sending a request with React Server Components?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

As the title says I am trying to check if my user is logged on, and if they are an admin.
This is the code:

```
import LoginFormComponent from "@/components/admin/login-form-component/login-form-component";
import LogoComponent from "@/components/logo-component/logo-component";
import IsAdminFunction from "@/scripts/requests/user/is-admin-function";
import { cookies, headers } from "next/headers";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export default async function AdminLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const staticData = await fetch(`http://localhost:8878/api/user/isadmin`, {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include", // Include cookies with the request
  })
    .then((response) => response.json()) // Parse the response as JSON
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data); // Print the response data
      return data; // Return the response data for further processing
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error); // Log any errors
      throw error; // Re-throw the error for further handling
    });

  console.log(staticData);
  return (
    <>
       // this is the same as the fetch above, but this one is axios, 
       both are behaving identically
      {(await IsAdminFunction()).success == true ? (
        children
      ) : (
        <div className="center-div">
          <LogoComponent size={50} />
          <LoginFormComponent />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

For some reason it always tells me that my user is not an admin, even though I've logged on already. I found out on my backend that the cookies are null, and I've tried adding it manually, but when I use cookies or headers from **next/headers** it just gives me this error.

```
Error: Page with `dynamic = "error"` couldn't be rendered statically because it used `cookies`.
```

I know I am doing something wrong here, how should I approach this? I am also using   `"next": "14.0.4",`.